# I need motion detection on a RTSP stream

Tags: video, motion, rtsp

I have my camera streaming through VLC using a separate (slower) computer because my iMac is too far from the window. I was curious if there was software that could take streaming video and watch it for motion (take shots/etc). The software can be win/lin/mac, just as long as it can keep an eye on the people wrecking my christmas lights outside!

Answer (score 3):

VLC has a motion detect video filter. Its under `Preferences->All->Video->Filters`

Comment: +1 because I had no idea this existed. I wonder how it could be utilized.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution may be the Motion project (https://motion-project.github.io/). It grabs and analyzes video from v4l-devices and RTSP streams, with the ability to save both image snapshots and grab video if motion is detected. Supports multiple cameras with a reasonably low impact on system load.

Comment: Please add information about how this product solves OP. As it is currently written, this is a link-only comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at zoneminder. Its a more compex solution, but has motion detection.